# How to use 'cons' without generating nested lists in Scheme?

Tags: list, scheme, append

While attempting to generate a list of subsets that exist within two sets, I am running into an issue with **cons**. A procedure takes in a list named **result** and attempts to construct a new list out of **result** and the **car** of another set. So far, the set is generated with the correct elements, but they are contained within a size **N** nested list, where N is the number of nestings and the number of elements within the subset for which I am searching.

How can I apply **cons** with **result** without creating a nested list?

Example:

```
;These are two sets that I will be checking
(define s1 '(1 2 3 4))
(define s2 '(1 2 3))
;Result from running these lists through my procedure
(((() . 1) . 2) . 3)
;What I want to have generated
(1 2 3)
```

I need to be able to call  `(car list)` and receive `1` not `((() . 1) . 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `(((() . 1) . 2) . 3)` is not a nested list - it's not a list at all. `(((() 1) 2) 3)` would be a nested list. `(((() . 1) . 2) . 3)` is a dotted pair whose first element is also a dotted pair.

So now to explain the behaviour you see: In the lisp family of languages `(cons a b)` creates a pair containing `a` as it's `car` and `b` as its `cdr`.

Now a list is either the empty list (`()`) or a pair whose `cdr` is also a list (the `car` might contain anything - if both the `cdr` and the `car` are a list, the list is called a nested list).

A pair that is not a list is called a dotted pair. This what you're creating here because you're calling `cons` with a second argument which is not a list.

#### Conclusion:

You can not use `cons` to append to the end of the list. If you need to append to the end of a list, you can use `concat` with a single-element list as the second argument.

Note however that appending to the end of a list, is an `O(n)` operation while appending at the front (using `cons`) is an `O(1)` operation, so if possible you should change your algorithm, so it only needs to append at the front.

Comment: I was incorrectly passing a dotted pair as the first argument of **cons**. When I changed the order as follows, everything works. 

    ;Broken method
    (cons result (car s2))
    ;Works correctly
    (cons (car s2) result)

Comment: 2 good rules: The second argument to cons should be a list, and every list is ended by `'()`, meaning a list with three sublists has 4 empty lists inside.