# Scheme - Using cons properly to create lists

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I've been trying to solve exercise 2.20 of SICP, where "dotted-tail" notation is introduced. My problem is that, instead of returning a proper list with results, my function returns a nested list.
I know that there is something wrong with the way I'm calling cons, but I still have no clue of how to solve the issue.

So here is my function:

```
(define (same-parity first . items)

  (define (speccar items)
    (cond ((null? items) 2) 
          ((not (pair? items)) (modulo items 2))
          (else (modulo (car items) 2))))

  (define (iter-parity first items result)
    (let ((parityFirst (modulo first 2)) (samepar (speccar items)))
      (if (null? items)
          result
          (if (= parityFirst samepar)
              ;; This next line is where the problem is...
              (iter-parity first (cdr items) (cons (list result) (list (car items))))
              (iter-parity first (cdr items) result)))))

  (iter-parity first items first))
```

Test:

```
(same-parity 1 2 3 4 5)
((((1) 3)) 5)
```

Now, I've read the following answers that deal with a similar problem:

[Cons element to list vs cons list to element in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213072/cons-element-to-list-vs-cons-list-to-element-in-scheme)

[How to use 'cons' without generating nested lists in Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109317/how-to-use-cons-without-generating-nested-lists-in-scheme)

They certainly make it clear where the problem is coming from, but how does one go about to actually implement a proper solution?
And, if possible, what is the correct way of "thinking" in Scheme to avoid these traps/pitfalls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incorrectly building the output list - remember: the first argument  to `cons` should be the current element and the second argument, the result list.

Also, given that you're using tail recursion, you'll have to `reverse` the output at the end to preserve the same order as in the original list. Try this:

```
(define (same-parity first . items)
  (define (speccar items)
    (cond ((null? items) 2) 
          ((not (pair? items)) (modulo items 2))
          (else (modulo (car items) 2))))
  (define (iter-parity first items result)
    (let ((parityFirst (modulo first 2))
          (samepar (speccar items)))
      (if (null? items)
          (reverse result)
          (if (= parityFirst samepar)
              (iter-parity first
                           (cdr items)
                           (cons (car items) result))
              (iter-parity first
                           (cdr items)
                           result)))))  
  (iter-parity first items (list first)))
```

The above solution can be greatly simplified if we use built-in procedures (don't reinvent the wheel!). This is the recommended way to write programs in Scheme - adhering to a functional style:

```
(define (same-parity head . tail)
  (if (even? head)
      (filter even? (cons head tail))
      (filter  odd? (cons head tail))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(same-parity 1 2 3 4 5)
=> '(1 3 5)
```